# VSC does not find package in monorepo (cannot find name [package])

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've setup a monorepo in typescript. The issue I'm facing is that my testing framework cannt be found (which visual studio code could before switching to a monorepo).

I get the following error: Cannot find name 'jest' or 'describe'... etc.
I think visual studio code cannot find the jest npm package. When I open de /cli, /server, /shared folder only the package does get detected by VSC.

This is my folder structure:

```
/cli
   node_modules
   src
   tsconfig.json
/server
   node_modules
   src
   tsconfig.json
/shared
   node_modules
   src
   tsconfig.json
tsconfig.base.json
tsconfig.json
```

My tsconfig.base.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2015"
    ],
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "paths": {
      "@shared/*": [
        "./shared/src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./server"
    },
    {
      "path": "./cli"
    },
    {
      "path": "./shared"
    }
  ]
}
```

My cli tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "..",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "types": [
      "jest"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "../shared/src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```

A small example where the error occurs:

```
import { getUserInput } from "./console";
import { createInterface, ReadLineOptions } from "readline"; <----- error readline not found
jest.mock("readline"); <----- error jest not found
```

I hope you could help me out with setting this up.

**EDIT:**
I found out that when I remove the `"**/*.test.ts"` out of the exclude it works again like expected. But when compiling, I don't want the tests to get included...

Answer (score 1):

You want to try this.

1. Create a `tsconfig.build.json` with the current settings of `tsconfig.json`, excluding your test files:

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    // your specific compiler options for this module
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```

2. Extend `tsconfig.json` with your new `tsconfig.build.json`, and remove the tests exclusion:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.build.json",
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
  ]
}
```

3. Adjust your build command in `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "server",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -b tsconfig.build.json"
  }
}
```

Your previous configuration was unable to resolve and type-check Jest members because you explicitly instructed typescript to ignore your test files.

I found this answer for myself when looking at other monorepos like [typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-internal](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/b5b3be0/packages/eslint-plugin-internal) doing the same.